# Make the product page as homepage WooCommerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I'd like to make the product's page as homepage. But this product's page I created with Elementor Pro. I'm trying to use the shortcode [product_page id=99]. But it imports the standard page of theme, not the page I've created with Elementor. Someone knows how to do this?

Comment: Then try to use the correct page id.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your backend or frontend. But it could be.